# how to insert images in nativescript from local file (angular)

Tags: ios, angular, image, nativescript

Currently trying to display an image from my local on my ios app that i've developed using nativescript and not having any luck.

Template:

```
<GridLayout class="page page-content">
    <StackLayout>
        <Image src="~/img/icon.jpg" stretch="none"></Image>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

File structure:

[image]

Not really sure what im doing wrong, i even tried to play around with the different path of the image.

"~/app/img/icon.jpg" and even put the direct path on there with no luck.

EDIT:

OK so i tried uploading a smaller image and that seemed to go in fine. Any way to optimize an image to work on nativescript?

Comment: If you are using webpack (`--bundle`), did you try `res://icon`?

Comment: hmm i tried using res:// and still no luck. I'm just using the default webpack configuration from the nativescript cli build

Comment: As an additional feature for Android, NativeScript supports decodeWidth and decodeHeight. These properties will downsample your image so that it will take less memory. The goal is to avoid as much as possible out of memory exceptions caused by images being loaded into memory and at the same time display crispy images.

Comment: you can also try loadMode="async" useCache

Answer (score 3):

Create images folder inside your App folder and place path like this:-

```
~/app/images/logo.png
```

Comment: This answer works for me! @jeremy: This answer should be accepted.